# How to send a POST request to Firebase REST API in react

Tags: reactjs, firebase, rest, express, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to sign in with OAuth credentials which involves  issuing an HTTP POST request to the Auth verifyAssertion endpoint. How would I go about doing this syntactically? I'm trying to follow this firebase documentation but they use curls for the examples.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential

The endpoint is [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You can either choose the native fetch api with

window.fetch('https://url-you-want-to-post-to.com/', {method: 'POST', body: { //body data } })

or you can use a third-party library like axios (although you need to npm install it first and then import it)

Comment: In the link it asks for a requestUri. What is that exactly? And do I have to include all the body paramters in the data?